# Creating a base date for analysis in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, custom-datetimepicker

I have a problem where i want to set a base date to a date time variable in the database. I would then use the base date for my aggregations. And the days subsequent to this base date would be categorised as Day1, Day2 and so on.[image]

So for example, if I want to see cohorts of orders created by the base date - I would want the  calculated after this date. I don't want to do this using a date filter.

Image below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could use the DATE function to convert your field, like this:

DATE([Acquisition Date])

If you don't already have the year value stored, but have a method in mind to add it, you could use MONTH([Acquisition Date]) to obtain the month and date and DAY([Acquisition Date]) to obtain the date.  You could then use MAKEDATE function to build the date or MAKEDATETIME function to build the datetime value.

Once it's stored as a date value, you could use DATEADD to add and subtract days to it as needed.

There are multiple formulas available for converting Tableau dates, described here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No so like my date field is a Date/time variable. I need to change that to the picture mentioned above. I need to set a base date - for example, 20-2-2022 and 21-2-2-22 would essentially be Day 1.

Comment: See the link that Brook provided for all kinds of functions for working with dates. The function DateDiff() might be useful for example.